# Locking theads in phpbb3 but keeping them visible in the thread list

Tags: phpbb3

Is there a way I can lock threads, or make them 'private' to a certain usergroup in phpbb3 so that the users can still see the threads/forums in the list, but know they redistricted from accessing them until they 'upgrade' to a higher user level.

I know you can 'hide' threads from a user group, but I still want them to be able to know what threads are there as a guest to help build value in the forum and encourage the guest to consider an upgrade.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

there is no possibility for your request in a standard phpBB3 installation, it's possible through changing a few lines of codes though.

Open `viewforum.php` and change the following lines:

```
if ($auth->acl_get('f_read', $forum_id))
```

to

```
if ($auth->acl_gets('f_list', 'f_read', $forum_id))
```

and

```
if (!$auth->acl_get('f_read', $forum_id))
```

to

```
if (!$auth->acl_gets('f_list', 'f_read', $forum_id))
```

After changing these lines everybody that's allowed to see the forum should be able to see the topics in the forum but not read them.